# Django doesn't render 404 page when passing to nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I want to show Django custom 404 page by nginx when passing url not exists.
But It seems like nginx simply shows the 404 page without Django rendering. How could I fix it. Here are my Django and nginx settings.

In myblog/urls.py

```
urls.py

handler404 = 'views.handler404'
```

In myblog/views.py

```
views.py

def handler404(requests):
    return render(requests, '404.html', status=404)
```

In templates/404.html

```
templates/404.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    {# some 404 content #}
{% endblock %}
```

In nginx.conf

```
nginx.conf

location /404.html {
        alias /my/path/templates/404.html;
    }
    error_page 404 500 403 /404.html;
    uwsgi_intercept_errors on;
```

And the 404 page show like this: (it's a sample)
[404.page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XLaC.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you setting an alias in your nginx config? That just causes nginx to render the Django template, which is not what you want. As regards your handler404, I can't see why but it isn't being loaded - if it was you would get an error because you are accepting the wrong arguments for that function (it needs to accept 2 arguments, `request` and `exception`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So alias causes nginx to render html. It's interesting.

Comment: @solarissmoke Sorry to nitpick, but that alias causes nginx to _serve_ the Django template as a normal html file, not _render_ it; none of the templating is rendered